# how to delete a profile in ~/.aws/config file

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am new to aws and very new to linux. I created profiles in ~/.aws/config

```
    [default]
    [profile admin]
    region = us-east-1
    [profile serverless]
    region = ap-southeast-1
    [profile dev]
    admin_access_key = blablabla
    admin_secret_key = blablabla
```

But how do I delete them? using the command line or editing the file directly?

Comment: Edit it and remove the section you do not need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use your favorite text editor and delete the profile you do not need The profiles are delimited by the next profile. If you want to delete profile `serverless`.

```
[default]
[profile admin]
region = us-east-1
[profile dev]
admin_access_key = blablabla
admin_secret_key = blablabla
```

Comment: thanks im used to windows and and opening files in windows explorer. Now Im at a lost at Vi text editor! Anyway I was able to edit it.